# EventHandler in WPF - Change in one element affects another

Tags: c#, wpf, events, event-handling

I have a stackpanel with a TextBlock and a ComboxBox and the I have a TextBox acting as a search field.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
    <TextBlock Text="Group Filter" Margin="7,0,0,0"/>
    <ComboBox Text ="{Binding GroupFilter}" Height="30" Width="130" Margin="0,4,0,0" 
        Padding="5" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupFilterEnum}}"
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>

<TextBox Text="{Binding SingleFilter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Height="30" Width="140" Margin="0,20,0,0" Padding="5" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Search single Id...">
</TextBox>
```

So basically I have a data set and what you can do is you can filter the data based on either a predefined setting from theGroupFilterEnum or you can enter a filter value yourself in the TextBox.

What I try to do is:

When the TextBox is empty things should just be as they are. When the TextBox has a value I would like to add the following to the ComboBox to indicate that the ComboBox is inactive when there is a value in the TextBox:

```
IsEditable="False" 
IsHitTestVisible="False" 
Focusable="False" 
Foreground="{StaticResource MaterialDesignBodyLight}"
```

I have tried to make an TextChanged EventHandler for the TextBox like:

```
private void textChangedEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var text = sender.ToString().Replace("System.Windows.Controls.TextBox: ", "");

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
    {

    }
}
```

But I don't really know how to refer to the ComboBox from this EventHandler. I am fairly new to this, so I haven't reallty done a lot of EventHandlers. Is this the way to do it? If yes,  could someone please help me with the Eventhandler?
Or maybe there is a better way? Directly in the xaml file maybe?

All help is highly appreciated and please let me know if additional information is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's quite easy, you can [cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions) the `sender` to a `ComboBox` like `var comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;`, off course this can fail and throw an exception, so it's generally recommended to do a check like `if (sender is ComboBox comboBox) { comboBox.IsEditable = false; /* more code */ }`

Comment: But sender in this case will be a TextBox, so I can't really cast it as ComboBox, right? So I need to refer to this ComboBox from the TextBox's EventHandler I assume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the `ComboBox` properties you want to change to the `Text` property of the `TextBox` using a converter that you would need to implement ([here is the example)](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/).

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox"/>
<ComboBox Focusable="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource EmptyStringToBooleanConverter}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a control that can be used like a textBox or comboBox, you are not in the good way.

The comboBox control have a property **IsEditable** which permit to write or select a value.

Try this : `<ComboBox IsEditable="True"/>`

Else, you can give a name to your control and you will able to get it in your code behind by typing his name.

The result here : [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90LuL.jpg)
(And I'm sorry for my english, I'm french).

Comment: Hi :) I might misunderstand your suggestion, but it does not seem to be exactly what I was trying to do - thanks a lot for your contribution though.